# After running babel-loader through web pack, 'this' is undefined in component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm new in ES6 and I try to build my code with `webpack` and `babel-loader` but for some reason the output looks strange.

**jsx file:**

```
class WmSpanButton extends React.Component {    
  onClickLocal(){
  this.props.onClick(); // < ---- ERROR this is undefined
}    

  render() {
    return   <button
      onClick={this.onClickLocal}
      className={'md-button md-blue-theme md-ink-ripple'} style={this.props.buttonStyle}>
      <p style={{margin: '0px'}}>
        <span style={this.props.buttonTextStyle}>{this.props.text}</span>
      </p>
    </button>
  }
}
```

after running web pack I get:

```
var WmSpanButton = function (_React$Component) {
        _inherits(WmSpanButton, _React$Component);

        function WmSpanButton() {
            _classCallCheck(this, WmSpanButton);

            return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, Object.getPrototypeOf(WmSpanButton).apply(this, arguments));
        }

        _createClass(WmSpanButton, [{
            key: 'onClickLocal',

            value: function onClickLocal() {
                console.log('hahahahahah');
                this.props.onClick();
            }
        }, {
            key: 'render',
            value: function render() {
                return React.createElement(
                    'button',
                    {
                        onClick: this.onClickLocal,
                        className: 'md-button md-blue-theme md-ink-ripple', style: this.props.buttonStyle },
                    React.createElement(
                        'p',
                        { style: { margin: '0px' } },
                        React.createElement(
                            'span',
                            { style: this.props.buttonTextStyle },
                            this.props.text
                        )
                    )
                );
            }
        }]);

        return WmSpanButton;
    }(React.Component);
```

And when I click on button, actually I call method `onClickLocal`, I get an error:

> react.min.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

In line `this.props.onClick();` **'this' is undefined**

What Im doing wrong?

my web pack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
 tile_templates: ['./main.js']
},
  output: {
        path: './build',
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: "bundle",
        libraryTarget: "umd"
      },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not `webpack` problem, you need just set `this` for `onClickLocal`

```
class WmSpanButton extends React.Component { 
   constructor() {
      this.onClickLocal = this.onClickLocal.bind(this)
   }

   // ... 
}
```

or you can use `arrow function` instead of `.bind`

```
<button onClick={ () => this.onClickLocal() }></button>
```